# Algorithm for user profiling without distinct profiles

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, artificial-intelligence, supervised-learning

I am trying to design an algorithm that takes in a new user with the variables `department, location, job_role` etc. and I want a machine-learning algorithm to decide what software and hardware this new user would need.

I am rattling my brain thinking how I could get this to work - 
I could use a supervised learning approach and train a model with a dataset of already employed users and the software and hardware they use, however, the variables in this dataset would be extensive as, through one-hot encoding, each user object would have to have variables that represent each possible software or hardware a user could own. Or can my dataset have a collection of user objects but not each object has the same software/hardware variables?

I'm very confused about how to go about this so any insight would help. I'm probably looking at going about this the wrong way.

Comment: You are possibly better off asking this question over in the data science site, instead of stack overflow, as you seem to want to know more about the algorithms and data prep. Neither of which is explicitly about programming.

Comment: Okay thanks will do